# Find first value of column and assign to separate coulmn pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume that I have the following dataset

```
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1, 2], 
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])
```

How do I find the first element of the column `Value` and assign it as a separate column in `df` grouped by `Id`? Such that `df` would look like

```
        Date  Id  Value  First
0 2015-01-01   1    0.5   0.5
1 2015-01-27   1    0.5   0.5
2 2015-01-31   1    0.5   0.5
3 2015-02-01   1    2.0   0.5
4 2015-02-03   1    2.0   0.5
5 2015-02-15   1    2.0   0.5
6 2015-02-28   1    2.0   0.5
7 2015-03-01   1    3.0   0.5
8 2015-03-17   1    3.0   0.5
9 2015-03-31   1    3.0   0.5
```

This seems an easy problem, but I can't figure out the solution. Grateful for any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Can you do `df['first'] = df['value'].iloc[1]`?

Comment: I'll try that! Seems elegant enough.

Comment: @LondonRob why not `df['first'] = df['value'].iloc[0]`?

Comment: Semantically speaking unless your df just has a single Id then really you need to perform a `groupby` or construct a lookup and merge the values back to your df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on 'Id' column, call [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first) to return the first value for that group, this returns a Series with 'Id' as the index, you can then call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) on the orig df 'Id' column to perform a lookup and assign the corresponding value for each 'Id':

```
In [127]:
df['First'] = df['Id'].map(df.groupby('Id')['Value'].first())
df

Out[127]:
        Date  Id  Value  First
0 2015-01-01   1    0.5    0.5
1 2015-01-27   1    0.5    0.5
2 2015-01-31   1    0.5    0.5
3 2015-02-01   1    2.0    0.5
4 2015-02-03   1    2.0    0.5
5 2015-02-15   1    2.0    0.5
6 2015-02-28   1    2.0    0.5
7 2015-03-01   1    3.0    0.5
8 2015-03-17   1    3.0    0.5
9 2015-03-31   1    3.0    0.5
```

Output from `first`:

```
In [128]:
df.groupby('Id')['Value'].first()

Out[128]:
Id
1    0.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```